# Issue in multiline matching using perl one liner

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to use Perl one liner, for matching a multi line pattern.
My file "new" will look like something below.

```
foo
bar
foo1
bar1
go

bye
bar2
```

Intention is to match first four lines, which is between foo and bar1.

My one liner is given below:

```
perl -0777 -n -e 'm/^foo.+?bar1/s && print' new
```

I am reading the file as a whole instead of line by line using `-0777`. Also, I have given `/s` modifier for making "." match a "\n" also. But this one liner is not serving the purpose. It is matching the enitre file here.

I may be missing something very fundamental here.
Can I have the help of experts on this, as this is something really annoying me for so long?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
perl -0777 -n -e 'm/^(foo.+?bar1)/s && print $1' new
```

By default, `print` will output `$_`, and the value of that variable is the whole file in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use a range `..` while still processing the file line by line:

```
perl -ne 'print if /^foo$/../^bar1$/' new
```

This may not work entirely as you want though because

1. It will print starting at `foo` to the end of the file if no `bar1` exists.
2. If there is more than one range of `foo` to `bar1` it will print each of them.